# iPhone-only gets detected as iPad app on iPad mini

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

We have a strange problem with `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` in our app.

Everything worked fine untill we tested iPhone-only target on iPad mini.

Normally you would expect `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` to return `Phone` in such case and system should display the app as 320x480 with toggles for (1x)/(2x) zoom mode but somehow on iPad mini this is not true. The function returns iPad thus our game thinks its iPad.

But thats not what is strange - also the system does not run the app in emulation mode but it gives us the bounds of the entire screen so we can render in actual iPad mini resolution.

How can this be possible and is it possible to disable this behaviour? What's more interesting is that when installed on regular iPad (new Air with iOS 9.0 and iPad 3 with iOS 8.0) it works as expected.

If this is any lead we recently switched from plain old plisted icons and launch images to Asset Catalogues and storyboard for launch image.

Comment: Why are you even calling `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` in an iPhone-only app?

Comment: We have a common codebase that is able to operate on any screen resolution. Usually we just do single Universal App but when working with publisher they require separate targets for iPhone/iPad, we still need to detect at runtime if we are running on iPhone or iPad. But thats not the problem, we can in fact stop using this and #define some symbols but... it still doesn't explain why iPhone app acts like iPad app on iPad mini.